# User front end plugin with image upload

Tags: wordpress, frontend, posts

I am searching for a Wordpress plugin, that allows user to write a post, edit it and allows to  set a featured post image and all that in the frontend. 
The only plugin that I have found was WP User Frontend, but there is missing the upload option for the Featured-image and I can modify the post from other people when i am logged in as normal user.

My goal is something similar like in http://www.deviantart.com/ from the function.

So what I need for the user:

1. All in Frontend
2. New Post Site ( with Title, Description, Upload Featured-image )
3. Edit Post ( with Title, Description, Upload Featured-image )
4. User can moderate there comments
5. Delete Post

It would be great if someone can help me.

Thanks and greatings

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Post Site ( with Title, Description, Upload Featured-image ) -  Gravity Forms

Edit Post ( with Title, Description ) - http://scribu.net/wordpress/front-end-editor

User can moderate there comments - Not sure. Search around and you might find something.

Delete Post - Easy to do with custom functionality. Google for wp_delete_post()

Front end login, registration and edit profile (outside of the backend) - http://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder/

I guess in the end you'll need a developer to put all these together into a cohesive structure.

Comment: Thx that helps already a lot. Sorry that I cant give you a thumb up, I dont have enough reputation for it.

Comment: Is there any free plugin that allows user's profile pic upload from front end?

Answer (score 0):

I all honesty I don't think you'll find one that achieves what you want. I was looking to do something similar and ended up having to research and write it myself, whcih wasn't a bad thing as I did learn alot!